# How to implement google authentication check

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement simple auth check to  decide whether to go to one page or another, but the check didn't go well.
Any suggestions what to do?

```
 _isAuth = false
    @override
  void initState() {
    if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() !=null){
      _isAuth = true;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ScopedModel<CProductModel>(
          model: _model,
          child: MaterialApp(
            routes: {
              '/': (BuildContext context) =>
                  !_isAuth ? LoginPage() : Products(_model),
```

EDIT: I tried this too:

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool _isAuth = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(_isAuth);

    if (googleSignIn.currentUser != null) {
      setState(() {
        print(_isAuth);

        _isAuth = true;
      });
    }
    super.initS
```

The routing inside the app seems to work, but if i close to app and come again every time i end up in the login screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
```

will give a Future object, So when you used at

```
   @override
  void initState() {
    if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() !=null){
      _isAuth = true;
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

here FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() is giving a future object and it will continue the execution, The execution will not stop.
When Future object returns an object your execution is already done.

Instead of using that try to use this way

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((_firebaseUser){
if(_firebaseUser!=null)
{
setState(() {
                  _isAuth=true
                });
}
});
```

Comment: Instead of this try to use StreamBuilder.